# http or http www to https www with only one redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

in .htacces I am trying to redirect to https://www

this is working fine

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but with 2 redirections I'd like to do it with only 1 redirection

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

it works fine but if the s is removed (step 2) I get 2 times www
1) https://www.domain.com --> 2) http://www.domain.com --> 3) https://www.www.domain.com

how can I redirect ?

```
 http://domain.com
 http://www.domain.com
 https://domain.com
to
 https://www.domain.com
```

with only one redirection  and no error whatever happen

thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

This does only one redirection. Yes, it is still two rules, but only one redirection will be performed:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
```

---

A more compact alternative, though not really faster or more efficient, would be that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSA]
```

The third condition in this *always* matches, it is only used to extract the part of the host name *without* a potantial leading `www.`.

Comment: on your first statement there is no needs for [OR] ?  after the first off ?

thank you

Comment: @ErickBoileau No, you need a logical `AND` there, not an `OR`, since that rule is meant to act as a more precise exception. You _could_ write that down in an explicit manner, but leaving it out defaults to `AND`. Maybe the explicit style is easier to read, you are right... I changed it.

Comment: I get an error



Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at .....
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Hm, strange. Try again with the `.*` you originally used as a pattern. Sorry, been a while since I last used that stuff. Don't really see any issue here...

Comment: [Sun Oct 16 10:49:20.156055 2016] [core:alert] [pid 14573:tid 140269630502656] [client 89.13.173.100:52363] /home/domain/public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: unknown flag 'AND'

Comment: Ah, ok, so it has been removed recently. As said: always been optional. I removed it.

Comment: I have removed the [AND] and it works
but if you browse and remove the www from the address
then you will keep browsing with https: //domain.com  without www

Comment: Indeed, missed that case. So I added a third rule. Still only one of the three will get applied.